# O que são meta tags de <head> e para que serve cada uma?

Tags: html, html-tags

O que são as meta tags contidas no `<head>`? Quais são e para que serve cada uma e quais são os pró e contra de utiliza-las?

Exemplo:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="description" content="descrição com palavras chaves">
<meta name="keywords" content="palavras chaves">
<meta name="author" content="nome do autor">
<meta name="copyright" content="nome do criador" />
```

Comment: Ao invés de votar para fechar esta questão seria mais proveitoso muda-la para algo como: Oque são meta tags e para que serve cada uma

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Meta tags são muito importantes para duas coisas:

- SEO, ou seja: Motores de busca;
- A forma que seu navegador irá interpretá-lo.

Quando falamos de SEO, seu uso é de suma importância para que seu website possa ser indexado corretamente.

> Meta Tag é um comando implementado no código de páginas web, dentro da
>   área Head do site (entre as tags  e ) para passar
>   instruções a programas externos ou ações mais simples, como por
>   exemplo informar qual a pessoa responsável pelo desenvolvimento da
>   página. Algumas Meta Tags são utilizadas para passar aos sites de
>   busca como o Bing e o Google instruções sobre o título da página e uma
>   breve descrição a ser exibida nos resultados de busca, quais páginas
>   devem ou não ser indexadas, dentre outras instruções.

**Importância de Meta Tags para SEO**

> Meta Tags são uma importante ferramenta de comunicação entre o
>   webmaster e os sites de busca, como vamos ver nos exemplos abaixo.
>   Para muitas pessoas, porém, SEO é apenas isso, Meta Tags. Isso está
>   longe de ser verdade. O Google utiliza perto de 250 variáveis para
>   determinar os resultados de busca, e as meta tags são apenas algumas
>   delas.

Existem várias meta tags, as mais importantes são:

**Title**

O campo `title` não é uma meta tag, mas é o mais importante comando em uma página web para SEO.

Exemplo de um Title:`<title>Project management software, online collaboration: Basecamp</title>`

**Meta Description (meta name="description")**

É a meta description que geralmente define a descrição exibida nos resultados do Google. Descreva o conteúdo da página de uma forma a estimular o interesse das pessoas em conhecer mais sobre o conteúdo da página, para aumentar a visitação do seu site.

Exemplo de um Meta Description: `<meta name="description" content="Veja no Terra as últimas notícias e as melhores coberturas ao vivo do Brasil e do Mundo, Esportes, Diversão, Vida e Estilo, assista os melhores vídeos no TerraTV e ouça as melhores músicas no Sonora." />`

**Meta Keywords (meta name="keywords")**

Há muitos anos atrás, os algoritmos dos sites de busca tinham certa dificuldade em interpretar a relevância de sites para determinadas palavras-chave e utilizavam o conteúdo da meta keyword para ajudá-los a interpretar o conteúdo das páginas. Rapidamente os webmasters perceberam que bastava incluir uma infinidade de palavras nessa tag para aparecer nas buscas, mesmo para palavras não relacionadas ao conteúdo da página.

A experiência do usuário era comprometida ao ser direcionada a uma página que no final das contas não possuía o conteúdo buscado. Os sites de busca evoluíram e hoje desconsideram a meta keyword. Uma vez que a meta keyword não é exibida ao usuário em qualquer momento, seja nos resultados de busca, seja no conteúdo do site, não há de fato qualquer razão lógica para que o Google a considere como um fator de relevância.

Por outro lado, utilizamos as meta keywords para pesquisar as palavras-chave de concorrentes desavisados. Entre nos sites de seus principais concorrentes e veja através dos meta keywords quais as palavras-chave que estes tentaram otimizar os seus sites.

Exemplo de um meta keyword: `<meta name="keywords" content="climática, previsão climática, desenvolvimento, tempo, clima,"/>`

**Meta Robots (meta name="robots")**

Essa meta tag foi criada para passar orientações aos robots dos buscadores. Cada página deve ter o seu meta robots. Veja alguns dos parâmetros que podem ser passados:

- `_index_`: indexe esta página - exiba-a em seus resultados de busca;
- `_noindex_`: não indexe esta página - não a exiba nos resultados de busca. Útil para páginas como de login e acesso à intranet;
- `_follow_`: siga os links desta pagina para descobrir novas páginas (reveja Googlebot, robots);
- `_nofollow_`: nenhum dos links desta página deve ser seguido;
- `_nosnippet_`: orienta o site de busca a não exibir a descrição da página nos resultados de busca;
- `_noodp_`: orienta o Google não utilizar a descrição do diretório DMOZ em seus resultados (snippet);
- `_noarchive_`: instrui o Google a não exibir a versão em cache da página;
- `_noimageindex_`: não indexe nenhuma imagem da página.

*Exemplos de Meta Robots:*

- `<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">` - sintaxe mais comum de meta robots - orienta os buscadores a indexar o conteúdo da página e seguir todos os links para descobrir novas páginas
- `<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">` - orienta os buscadores a não indexar o conteúdo da página e impede-a de seguir os links para descobrir novas páginas

Nota: o comando para orientar ao Google a não indexar uma página pode também ser dado no arquivo robots.txt.

Fonte: http://www.seomarketing.com.br/meta-tags-google.php

**Existem meta tags que são muito importantes para informar ao seu browser como renderizar seu browser**

- `meta name="viewport"` é muito importante para que seu site seja executado em diferentes escalas e dispositivos;
- `meta charset` é o encoding que o browser deve utilizar para renderizar o site;
- `meta http-equiv="content-language"` indica o idioma do site.

As informações meta podem ser utilizados também por plugins, softwares e redes sociais...

Comment: Uma boa resposta, mas não é só para SEO, elas tem um fundamento e SEO é apenas parte disto, seria algo como: O uso delas é passar informações para softwares (sendo o navegador ou um plugin, um exemplo seria os mobiles) ou bots (que não são necessariamente só buscadores, um exemplo seria as redes sociais).

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu enviei antes de acabar a resposta. Eu a editei.

Comment: Ficou bom, apesar de faltar algo sobre as redes sociais e parecer estar muito focado no SEO, já é uma boa ótima resposta :) +1

Comment: É cara, é um assunto extremamente vasto. Eu me foquei em dizer o principal.

Comment: Oi Edgar. Não tenho nada contra usar conteúdo de fontes externas (aliás, você fez bem em fornecer o conteúdo e, principalmente, em citar a fonte!). Porém, é legal sempre dar uma revisada no texto pra que ele faça sentido aqui. Por exemplo, a frase "Temos uma página neste tutorial dedicada ao Title, consulte-a." não faz muito sentido numa resposta no SOPT, então eu creio que poderia (ou, deveria) ser eliminada. Outra coisa, os exemplos não estão aparecendo, procure usar o `marcador de código` para que eles sejam exibidos. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira foi mau cara. Eu revisei o texto e acabou passado desapercebido.

Comment: @EdgarMunizBerlinck Sem problemas. :)

Comment: Obrigado galera, o que importa é compartilhar informações ;)

Answer (score 5):

As tags meta são informações sobre a página utilizadas, principalmente, pelos buscadores e navegadores.

`<meta charset="UTF-8">` informa ao navegador a codificação de caracteres que deve ser utilizada.

As tags com o atributo `name` com valores: `description`, `keywords`, `author`, `copyright`, etc fornecem informações para os buscadores.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` informa ao navegador como a área de visualização deve se comportar.

`<meta name="robots" content="noarchive">` informa aos buscadores como a página deve ser indexada.

`<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="pt-br">` informa o idioma do conteúdo para o navegador e buscadores.

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content=" 5 ;url=http://www.exemplo.com/">` utilizada para criar redirecionamentos.

O artigo [Meta Tags - O que são e como utilizá-las](http://www.infowester.com/metatags.php) tem uma descrição detalhada sobre as tags `<meta>`.

Ainda existem outras, como as do [OpenGraph](http://ogp.me/), que são utilizadas pelo Facebook.