# Quais são as meta tags que não devem faltar no cabeçalho de um bom site?

Tags: html

Quais são as meta tags que não devem faltar no cabeçalho de um bom site e por que?

Obs.: Não estou perguntando o que é são meta tags, e sim quais são.
A questão [O que são meta tags de <head> e para que serve cada uma?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52353/155) já explica o que são meta tags.

Comment: Não estou perguntando o que são, e sim quais são as recomendadas para adicionar em meus sites.

Comment: Guilherme, veja que a outra pergunta tinha um título semelhante a sua pergunta, mas ela foi editada porque a comunidade  havia fechado por ser "principalmente baseadas em opiniões."

Answer (score 3):

### Title

Não é exatamente uma meta tag, mas depois do conteúdo da página é a melhor coisa em termos de SEO. Não use mais do que 70 caracteres. É desnecessário especificar o nome do seu site aqui, use somente um texto fortemente relacionado com o conteúdo da página. Capriche aqui!

```
<title>O título vem aqui</title>
```

---

### Meta description

A descrição da página. Útil para o SEO. Máximo de 160 caracteres.

```
<meta name="description" content="descrição aqui">
```

---

### Meta robots

Indica aos buscadores certos procedimentos em relação à página. Valores:

- `index`: a página deve ser indexada (default)
- `noindex`: a página não deve ser indexada
- `follow`: os links da página devem ser seguidos (default)
- `nofollow`: os links da página não devem ser seguidos
- `none`: o mesmo que `noindex, nofollow`
- `noarchive`: o buscador não deve salvar a página em cache
- `noodp`: o buscador não deve utilizar a descrição de certos diretórios de links (ex.: dmoz.org)
- `nosnippet`: faz com que o Google exiba somente o link para a sua página na hora da busca, deixando de exibir a descrição, etc. (não recomendado)

OBS.: valores default não precisam ser especificados, ou seja, é desnecessário usar `index, follow`

OBS.: eu particularmente recomendo utilizar `noarchive`, para evitar que o Google salve sua página, porque se ele salvar uma determinada página e depois você se arrepender, é meio difícil a remoção. Algumas pessoas gostam que o Google salve em cache justamente para o caso de o site sair do ar temporariamente, assim as pessoas ainda conseguem visualizar o conteúdo da página.

---

### Meta googlebot

O mesmo que `robots`, mas é específico para o Googlebot.

```
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
```

---

### Meta keywords

As palavras-chaves relacionadas com o conteúdo da página. O Google não utiliza mais essa meta tag, mas outros buscadores (como Bing, Baidu) podem utilizar.

```
<meta name="keywords" content="palavra1, palavra 2, outra aqui">
```

---

### Meta author

O nome da pessoa que criou o conteúdo da página. Não ajuda no SEO, mas o Facebook por exemplo mostra o autor especificado nessa meta tag quando você compartilha um link.

```
<meta name="author" content="João Silva">
```

---

### Meta google

Indica ao Google que sua página não deve ser traduzida pelo Google Translate. Isso faz com que o Google deixe de exibir o link "Traduzir esta página" ao lado do link do seu site, na página de busca.

```
<meta name="google" content="notranslate">
```

Answer (score 2):

As meta tags mais básicas e que não podem deixar de existir são:

```
<meta name="description" content="Descrição sobre o conteúdoda página..." />
<meta name="keywords" content="palavras, chaves, sobre, seu, conteudo" />
```

Após estas, viriam as tags dos Robots, que configuram e guiam os robos de indexação dos sites de busca, mas estas não estão mais sendo tanto utilizadas pois os mecanismos do google já fazem o trabalho automaticamente:

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
//Não indexar e não seguir os links

<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="INDEX, NOFOLLOW">
//Indexar, mas não seguir os links

<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, FOLLOW">
//Não indexar, mas seguir os links

<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="INDEX, FOLLOW">
//Indexar e seguir os links
```

Caso necessite, também tem alguns meta tags que controlam a navegação como por exemplo:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
//Tempo para atualizar a pagina

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="x_seconds; url=http://www.yourhost.com/pagetosendto.html">
//Redirecionar a pagina após x segundos
```

E por último mas não menos importante, as meta tags que as redes sociais utilizam pra captar informação da página quando o link é compartilhado:

```
//Facebook
<meta property="og:title" content="..."/>
<meta property="og:description" content="..."/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://sua_url.com/foto-facebook.jpg"/>

//Twitter
<meta name="twitter:title" content="...">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="...">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://sua_url.com/foto-twitter.jpg">
```

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Caso fique com alguma dúvida ou queira ver mais meta tags [este post do acquire](http://www.iacquire.com/blog/18-meta-tags-every-webpage-should-have-in-2013) é bem completo sobre o assunto.

Comment: MetaTag **keywords** já era, mano.

Comment: A keywords não é mais usada?

Comment: Sempre que pesquiso sobre isso vejo indicações para usar, e eu sempre uso.

Comment: @GuilhermeJSantos
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.br/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html e http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/metatags.shtml