# Como funciona a meta tag?

Tags: seo, html-meta-tag

Eu vi nessa pergunta [O que são meta tags de <head> e para que serve cada uma?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/o-que-s%C3%A3o-meta-tags-de-head-e-para-que-serve-cada-uma/52397#52397) que se usar:

> `<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">` - orienta os buscadores a não indexar o conteúdo da página e impede-a de seguir os links para descobrir novas páginas.

Então em uma página de login, eu deveria colocar na página de login mesmo essa meta tag ou inserí-la na página principal do intranet?

Seria uma estrutura semelhante a inicio -> login -> intranet

E eu não quero mostrar somente a página intranet e o que estiver relacionado a ela.

Comment: Poxa gente me ajuda ai por favor

Comment: Coloca em todas as páginas que você não quer indexar.

Comment: leia isso que acho que vai te esclarecer  https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag?hl=pt-br